# How to write Java script that advances to a link after a link has been clicked "X" # of times

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a Text-Adventure port of The Stanley Parable, and one of the endings requires pressing a button for 8 hours. Instead of 8 Hours, I want the game to advance to the next link after 800 clicks on the link, any idea how I would code this?

Comment: @Filburt come on man, it's not easy as a newcomer to distinguish the two, the name sounds like a nickname. Have some class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Its simple but you get the idea. Rest you should try to accomplish yourself.

```js
var clicks = 0;
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function(){
  clicks++; 
  if(clicks == 5) {
   window.location.href = 'www.yourlink.com';
  }
 
}
```

```html
<button id="button">
Click
</button>
```